# Calling function from web service not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a web service in C# for my ASP.NET website and I'm trying to use one of the functions from the web service in the website but nothing is happening.

Code in website:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Code in website C# file:

```
localhost.Storage getStorage = new localhost.Storage();
protected void checkItem()
    {
        int itemsleft = getStorage.checkStorage();
        Label1.Text = itemsleft.ToString();
```

Code in web service:

```
 public static int Item1 = 100;
 [WebMethod]
 public int checkStorage()
    {
        return Item1;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is happening when you step through your code? Are breakpoints being hit?

Comment: Can you provide details about your service? Is this a WCF service? If yes, can you access its svc file? (`localhost://.../service.svc`)